# Handling attachment events in an outlook add-in

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop, outlook-addin

Is anyone aware of a technique I could use to override someone opening an email attachment within an outlook add-in?

Essentially what I'm being asked to do, is for certain attachments, to change the behavior so instead of opening the attachment the user is redirected to a webpage.

I can hook into the attachment context menu with [`Application.AttachmentContextMenuDisplay`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb175107%28v=office.12%29.aspx) however that is not fired if the user simply double clicks on an email attachment.

Environment used is VS2010, c#, and outlook 2007/2010.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take a look at the `ItemEvent` [`BeforeAttachmentRead`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.itemevents_10_beforeattachmentreadeventhandler.aspx) and [`BeforeAttachmentPreview`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.itemevents_10_event.beforeattachmentpreview.aspx). See [this related post](http://www.add-in-express.com/forum/read.php?FID=1&TID=7674) for reference.

```cs
((Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event)MailItem).BeforeAttachmentRead += new Outlook.ItemEvents_10_BeforeAttachmentReadEventHandler(ItemEvents_BeforeAttachmentRead);
((Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event)MailItem).BeforeAttachmentPreview += new Outlook.ItemEvents_10_BeforeAttachmentPreviewEventHandler(ItemEvents_BeforeAttachmentPreview);
```

Comment: SilverNinja, 
That is almost exactly what I need. However with many types of attachments when double clicking in outlook you get a Open/Save/Cancel dialog. The open handler fires if they then click Open, but if they click "Save", they are prompted for a filename before the BeforeAttachmentWriteToTempFile event fires, and setting "cancel=true" in the handler causes outlook to pop a dialog "Outlook can not save the file". 

Ideally I'd like to get a handler to when they double click attachment, before the "Open/Save/Cancel" dialog to avoid this confusing behavior.